MariaDB won't restart, no idea what this log is telling me
Following a bunch of automatic server updates MariaDB keeps crashing and will not restart.  Pasted below are the last 100 lines of the mysqld log but I don't know what I am looking for here...  Then I try to restart mysql   Any help would be greatly appreciated.
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.5.24-MariaDB source revision 01f6abd1d4a929ee308f5b9287ac797a2e40d2b0 as process 13971
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=109647155015,109647155015
2024-05-13 11:07:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 2698 pages from redo log.
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.24 started; log sequence number 109706258966; transaction id 120884182
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'unix_socket' is disabled.
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.24-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2024-05-13 11:07:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240513 11:07:35
2024-05-13 11:08:36 65 [ERROR] mariadbd: Table './bugxexte_updsef/jos_rsform_config' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2024-05-13 11:08:36 65 [Warning] Checking table:   './bugxexte_updsef/jos_rsform_config'

2024-05-13 11:28:05 1220 [Warning] Checking table:   './hillorth_hill19/f572w_redirect_links'
2024-05-13 12:30:01 5345 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-13 12:30:03 5346 [ERROR] mariadbd: Table './hil_hill19/f572w_update_sites' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
2024-05-13 12:30:03 5346 [Warning] Checking table:   './hil_hill19/f572w_update_sites'
2024-05-13 13:24:56 8637 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-13 16:30:01 21349 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-14 16:30:01 115367 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-14 17:25:42 121371 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-14 20:30:01 132537 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-14 21:18:27 136067 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  0:30:01 148601 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  1:22:54 151846 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  1:34:03 152403 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  4:30:01 164804 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  5:24:17 168507 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  8:30:01 181001 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15  9:25:45 184469 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15 12:30:01 195173 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15 13:25:48 198296 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15 16:30:01 209046 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15 17:29:29 212801 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15 20:30:01 232217 [Warning] Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Restricted to 2016 pages due to innodb_buf_pool_dump_pct=25
2024-05-15 21:19:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240515 21:19:22
2024-05-15 21:19:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2024-05-15 21:19:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 109979833442; transaction id 121384395
2024-05-15 21:19:24 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete



I have not tried anything to solve the problem yet because I can't tell what it is...

When posting error logs, please do not skip any LINES that you think are unnecessary to get the best advice we can give.  It looks like you skipped 20 minutes of your error log between 11:08 and 11:28 there may have been some important kernels of information you could have shared with us to assist in resolving your issue.

Thank you for the suggestions.  In this case it finally came out that it was a problem related to a recent update.  The server runs on a VPS which runs on a kernel kept secure by kernelcare updates.  I can't update the kernel, only the VPS operator can and apparently the outdated kernel is responsible for the problems with MariaDB.  If you are troubleshooting on your own please see this post on the Plesk support site that shows how I worked around it.

Well done on asking first. There is no evidence of crashing or service unavailable from your logs.
/usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
...
/usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
...
/usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete

Indicates it isn't crashing. The lack of a shutdown message would indicate a hard kill via KILL -9 or the OOM killer of the OS.
mariadbd: Table './hil_hill19/f572w_update_sites' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Is an indication of just that. ref REPAIR TABLE. To fix use the SQL statement:
REPAIR TABLE hil_hill19.f572w_update_sites

On permission denied:
Access denied for user 'Cpanel::MysqlUtils::Unprivileged'@'localhost'

The cpanel support forum answer sees to indicate this is a version check (and hence can be ignored). Or you could create this user without giving it any grants and it can do almost nothing.
